# Research of a knee point on the the data

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am programming in python 3.x
I would like to implement a way to find the knee point mathematically or with a smart method to automatize the code for each bunch of data. I need to find this point to have the initial guess for my fit analysis. The image below show where I am searching the knee point.

Search of the knee point:
[image]

In this moment, I must choose the knee point value value like a boundary by eyes before implement a reasonable fit.

I was wondering if you have a suggestion on how to find the knee point in this situation. I am trying to put condition on the current peaks value to find a way to determine the knee but for now unsuccessfully.

The next image shows how is my fit analysis, because I have a linear fit before the knee point and after becomes like an exponential fit.

Fit analysis:
[image]

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: see this `https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed`

Comment: Thank you it is a good sistem but my data are too noisy is difficult to find the correct knee